# Convert from English Digits to Arabic ones in html page

Tags: javascript, css, ascii, arabic

I need to convert all English numbers that appear in a given HTML page to Arabic ones (to be independent from the user browser encoding). I prefer to use javascript or it will be great if this can be handled using CSS.

I found some pages doing this but I found that the Arabic letters are added with their ASCII representation in the source code. Does it mean that they are applying some sort of a java script function?

Any clue how can I do something like this?

Comment: You may need to be more specific, perhaps with examples, because "arabic numerals" are what you would probably consider ordinary numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals

Comment: Do you mean changing "one, two, three, fourteen" into "1, 2, 3, 14"?

Comment: You are right. I actually need to convert Arabic Numbers to Indian ones (i.e. 1234 to ١٢٣٤)

Comment: @Sarah - What do you mean by "I found that the Arabic letters are added with their ASCII representation in the source code." Can you give an example?

Comment: So, you want to convert Arabic numerals to Eastern Arabic numerals.

Comment: @McDowell - Like in this link http://www.almasry-alyoum.com/ when I view the source of this page, I find that Indian letters are put in their ascii representation (i.e. &#1634;&#1635;&#1639;)

@Alan - Yes, that's what I need

Comment: This is not really what you are asking, but is it not possible to just fix the encoding of the page? For example by adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >` to the head.

Comment: @Johannes - I tries this encoding but it didn't work for numbers. They are still displayed as they were

Comment: @Sarah: That page you link to does not use Arabic numerals in the source as far as I can see, but HTML-entities, like `&#1636;` for ٤

Comment: @johannes, yes, my question is: can it be using some sort of a javascript function to write arabic numerals in that form? cause I find it hard to believe that they are actually inserting the numbers in this form

Answer (score 49):

How about a straight replace function?

```
String.prototype.toIndiaDigits= function(){
 var id= ['۰','۱','۲','۳','۴','۵','۶','۷','۸','۹'];
 return this.replace(/[0-9]/g, function(w){
  return id[+w]
 });
}

// test

var S='The year 2009 has only 365 days';
alert(S.toIndiaDigits());

/*  returned value: (String)
The year ۲۰۰۹ has only ۳۶۵ days
*/
```

Comment: This will work provided the HTML and/or JavaScript source files are encoded as UTF-8 or some other Unicode-compatible encoding.

Comment: you can replace `id=[...` with `id='۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'`

Comment: what if I wanna convert an additional character, like `'.'` to `','` ?

Answer (score 15):

Convert English <> Arabic <> Persian

```js
    //English to Persian digits.
    String.prototype.EntoFa= function() {
      return this.replace(/\d/g, d => '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'[d])
    }
    
    //English to Arabic digits.
    String.prototype.EntoAr= function() {
      return this.replace(/\d/g, d =>  '٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'[d])
    }
    
    //Arabic to English digits.
    String.prototype.ArtoEn= function() {
      return this.replace(/[\u0660-\u0669]/g, 
        d => d.charCodeAt() - 1632)
    }
    
    //Persian to English digits.
    String.prototype.PetoEn= function() {
      return this.replace(/[\u06F0-\u06F9]/g, 
        d => d.charCodeAt() - 1776)
    }
    
    //Persian to Arabic digits.
    String.prototype.PetoAr= function() {
      return this.replace(/[\u06F0-\u06F9]/g, 
        d => '٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'[d.charCodeAt() - 1776])
    }
    
    //Arabic to Persian digits.
    String.prototype.ArtoPe= function() {
      return this.replace(/[\u0660-\u0669]/g, 
        d => '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'[d.charCodeAt() - 1632])
    }
    
    //Both Persian and Arabic to English digits.
    String.prototype.IntoEn= function() {
      return this.replace(/[\u06F0-\u06F9\u0660-\u0669]/g, 
        d => ((c=d.charCodeAt()) > 1775 ? c - 1776 : c - 1632))
    }
    
    //English to either Persian or Arabic digits.
    String.prototype.EntoIn= function(e) {
      return this.replace(/\d/g, 
        d => e ? '٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'[d] : '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'[d])
    }
    
    //English to Persian digits using unicode.
    String.prototype.EntoFaUni= function() {
      return this.replace(/\d/g, d => String.fromCharCode('0x06F'+d))
    }
    
    //English to Arabic digits using unicode.
    String.prototype.EntoArUni= function() {
      return this.replace(/\d/g, d => String.fromCharCode('0x066'+d))
    }
    
    //English to either Persian or Arabic digits.
    String.prototype.EntoInUni= function(e) {
      return this.replace(/\d/g, d => String.fromCharCode('0x06'+(e ? '6':'F')+d))
    }
    
    //examples
    let En = 'It is 30/08/2018 at 8:24 AM'
    let Pe = 'It is ۳۰/۰۸/۲۰۱۹ at ۸:۲۴ AM'
    let Ar = 'It is ٣٠/٠٨/٢٠١٩ at ٨:٢٤ AM'
    
    let PeAr = 'It is ۳۰/۰۸/۲۰۱۹ at ۸:۲۴ | AM It is ٣٠/٠٨/٢٠١٩ at ٨:٢٤ AM'
    
    //Persian <> Araibc <> English
    
    console.log(Ar.ArtoEn())
    console.log(Pe.PetoEn())
    console.log(Pe.PetoAr())
    console.log(Ar.ArtoPe())
    console.log(PeAr.IntoEn())

    //using array
    console.log(En.EntoFa())
    console.log(En.EntoAr())
    console.log(En.EntoIn(0))
    console.log(En.EntoIn(1))
    
    //using unicode
    console.log(En.EntoFaUni())
    console.log(En.EntoArUni())
    console.log(En.EntoInUni(0))
    console.log(En.EntoInUni(1))
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/P9Q/k891j0ts/95/)

Comment: while this may be a correct answer, it would be more valuable to other readers if you explained how it works

Comment: what for arabic to english

Comment: how to implement this in React.js?

Answer (score 14):

You will need to use JavaScript, but the procedure is quite straightforward. Assuming that the number you wish to convert is already in a string, then something like the following snippet of code will work:

```
function convertDigitIn(enDigit){ // PERSIAN, ARABIC, URDO
    var newValue="";
    for (var i=0;i<enDigit.length;i++)
    {
        var ch=enDigit.charCodeAt(i);
        if (ch>=48 && ch<=57)
        {
            // european digit range
            var newChar=ch+1584;
            newValue=newValue+String.fromCharCode(newChar);
        }
        else
            newValue=newValue+String.fromCharCode(ch);
    }
    return newValue;
}
```

The code isn't very pretty and can probably be written more efficiently, but essentially what it's doing is converting any char  from "0" to "9" by adding an offset value to make the character value now be in the unicode range for the Indic digits. The Indic digits range from \u0660 to \u0669 hence the conversion from European to Indic digits is just simple maths.

Comment: I appreciate the code. To whom wants to change the numerals from Indian to Arabic change the if statement to `if (ch>=1632 && ch<=1641)` and inside the if statement change the plus sign to minus `var newChar=ch-1584;`

Answer (score 12):

I know this is a very old post, but for other people coming here from google search that have same problem, there is a relatively new method called [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) which converts Number types to your preferred number system glyphs:

```js
(2500000).toLocaleString('ar-EG');
//outputs: "٢٬٥٠٠٬٠٠٠"
```

Comment: This method uses the country `Egypt` as the locale which is not necessary. Just use the locale `ar` followed by the numbering system (in this case Arabic Numbering System), like this `(2500000).toLocaleString('ar-u-nu-arab');`

Answer (score 8):

To explain this comment:

> Like in this link almasry-alyoum.com when I view the source of this page, I find that Indian letters are put in their ascii representation (i.e. `&#1634;&#1635;&#1639;`)

These are HTML character entities. The values are Unicode codepoints as defined by the [documentation](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt).

```
0660 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ZERO
0661 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ONE
0662 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT TWO
0663 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT THREE
0664 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT FOUR
0665 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT FIVE
0666 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT SIX
0667 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT SEVEN
0668 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT EIGHT
0669 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT NINE
```

So, ٠ ١ ٢ ٣ ٤ ٥ ٦ ٧ ٨ ٩ can be encoded as `&#x0660; &#x0661; &#x0662; &#x0663; &#x0664; &#x0665; &#x0666; &#x0667; &#x0668; &#x0669;` in a web page.

Note: `&#` for decimal values; `&#x` for hex.

Comment: Related to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676460/why-in-the-arabic-unicode-representation-of-arabic-numbers-there-is-2-representat

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the answers. No one has discussed handling decimal and thousand markers. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_point) for example. According to this page, these are the correct unicode characters:

- U+066B - Arabic Decimal Separator
- U+066C - Arabic Thousands Separator

Answer (score 3):

Edit for the first answer, convert English numbers to Arabic numbers:

```
String.prototype.toArabicDigits = function(){
var id = ['٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩'];
return this.replace(/[0-9]/g, function(w){
  return id[+w];
 });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The "ASCII equivalents" you are referring to are not actually that *at all*.

First of all, ASCII is a 7-bit character encoding in which characters like [Arabic-Indic Digit Two](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0662/index.htm) don't exist.

Secondly, what you are seeing are actually [HTML Entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html). To programmatically make a conversion from Latin numerals to these entities would require the exertion of a backend language like PHP, Perl, C#, etc.

Thirdly, the numeric value represented in the entities is their Unicode Code Point in decimal form.  So ٢ is the Unicode character at code point 1634 (decimal) or 0662 (hex), which is the more standard notation.

Lastly, I like ferdley's approach, but the tricky part will figuring out how to use his algorithm to replace only the numbers you want, and not numbers that otherwise appear in the HTML source, such as the pixel-width of an image.

Answer (score 1):

Give this JavaScript function  a string number and it will help you in converting  english to arabic

```
function GetArabicNumber(number) {
            var charIndex = 0;
            var NumericArabic = "";

            while (charIndex < number.length) {
                switch (number[(charIndex)]) {
                    case '.':
                        NumericArabic += ".";
                        break;

                    case '0':
                        NumericArabic += "٠";
                        break;

                    case '1':
                        NumericArabic += "١";
                        break;

                    case '2':
                        NumericArabic += "٢";
                        break;

                    case '3':
                        NumericArabic += "٣";
                        break;

                    case '4':
                        NumericArabic += "٤";
                        break;

                    case '5':
                        NumericArabic += "٥";
                        break;

                    case '6':
                        NumericArabic += "٦";
                        break;

                    case '7':
                        NumericArabic += "٧";
                        break;

                    case '8':
                        NumericArabic += "٨";
                        break;

                    case '9':
                        NumericArabic += "٩";
                        break;

                    default:
                        NumericArabic += number[(charIndex)];
                        break;
                }

                charIndex++;
            }

            return NumericArabic;
        }
```

Comment: Confirmed this method works by running on a complex document and checking with a native Arabic speaker.