# In Unicode, why are there two representations for the Arabic digits?

Tags: unicode, arabic

I was reading the specification of Unicode @ Wikipedia ([Arabic Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_Unicode))
and I see that each of the Arabic digits has 2 Unicode code points.
For example 1 is defined as U+0661 and as U+06F1.

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

According to the [code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/), U+0660 .. U+0669 are ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT values 0 through 9, while U+06F0 .. U+06F9 are EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT values 0 through 9.

In the Unicode 3.0 book (5.2 is the current version, but these things don't change much once set), the U+066n series of glyphs are marked 'Arabic-Indic digits' and the U+06Fn series of glyphs are marked 'Eastern Arabic-Indic digits (Persian and Urdu)'.
It also notes:

- U+06F4 - 'different glyphs in Persian and Urdu'
- U+06F5 - 'Persian and Urdu share glyph different from Arabic'
- U+06F6 - 'Persian glyph different from Arabic'
- U+06F7 - 'Urdu glyph different from Arabic'

For comparison:

- U+066n: ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩
- U+06Fn: ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹

Or, enlarged by making the information into a title:

## U+066n: ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩

## U+06Fn: ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹

Or:

```
     U+066n    U+06Fn
0      ٠         ۰
1      ١         ۱
2      ٢         ۲
3      ٣         ۳
4      ٤         ۴
5      ٥         ۵
6      ٦         ۶
7      ٧         ۷
8      ٨         ۸
9      ٩         ۹
```

(Whether you can see any of those, and how clearly they are differentiated may depend on your browser and the fonts installed on your machine as much as anything else.  I can see the difference on 4 and 6 clearly; 5 looks much the same in both.)

Based on this information, if you are working with Arabic from the Middle East, use the U+066n series of digits; if you are working with Persian or Urdu, use the U+06Fn series of digits.  As a Unicode application, you should accept either set of codes as valid digits (but you might look askance at a sequence that mixed the two sets of digits - or you might just leave well alone).

Comment: +1: would have made that answer if you hadn't beaten me by 1 minute ;-)  It's a pity everybody seems to think that the difference doesn't matter and rush to make ill-advised answers...

Comment: Roughly this means that they should never actually have had two code points.  The fact that they look different in three different languages is a font issue and shouldn't have been encoded in the script.  There are a few issues like that with Urdu characters encoded in different points because they look different even though they are the same letter.  Thus the correct solution would have been a font to display the character differently if its Arabic or if its Urdu.  Joys of Unicode learning the Arabic script.

Comment: @Dwayne: yes, no, maybe.  I can see that argument, but then why did they not retarget code points U+0030..U+0039 and say that in Arabic fonts, those should appear as the Arabic digits.  There probably were good enough reasons for the decision — even if there weren't, that's the state of the standard.  Note that the presentation forms of Arabic letters are now in supplements.  The Arabic ranges are: Arabic in U+0600..U+06FF; Arabic Supplement in U+0750..U+077F; Arabic Extended-A in U+08A0..U+08FF; Arabic Presentation Forms-A in U+FB50..U+FDFF; and Arabic Presentation Forms-B in U+FE70..U+FEFF.

Comment: Yes, Urdu almost invariably uses the Heart-shaped 5, and not the round one... Best would be to normalize in your own program (if you're parsing). Maybe there's a lib for that. But then again, who would write these characters with a keybard is beyond me, maybe there's a mechanism for that.

Answer (score 4):

In general you should not hard-code such info in your application.

- On Windows you can use GetLocaleInfo with LOCALE_SNATIVEDIGITS.
- On Mac CFNumberFormatterCopyProperty with kCFNumberFormatterZeroSymbol.
- Or use something like [ICU](http://icu-project.org/).

There are Arabic countries that don't use the Arabic-Indic digits by default. So there is no direct mapping saying Arabic -> Arabic-Indic digits.

And the user might have changed the defaults in the Control Panel anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Which code do you prefer for representing the number 4, U+0664 or U+06F4?

(٤ or ۴ )?

To be consistent, let this choice guide which codes you use for 1, 2, and the other duplicate codes.