# How to convert unicode string to int in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

I have a string from a source which is a unicode digital number like this:

> n = ۱۱۷ => 117

now I want to convert this string to int. but when i try to use **Convert.ToInt** I get this exception.
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Maybe u should check out this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879437/how-to-convert-arabic-number-to-int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Int32 value = 0;
    if (Int32.TryParse(String.Join(String.Empty, "۱۱۷".Select(Char.GetNumericValue)), out value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        //....
    }
```

Comment: this solution was shortest and best method

Comment: @Navid_pdp11 no support here for number starting with `+` or `-`

Answer (score 2):

We will use the method [`GetNumericValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getnumericvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), to convert each character into a number. The documentation is clear:

> Converts a specified numeric Unicode character to a double-precision floating-point number.

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L41UzM)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        Console.WriteLine(ParseNumeric("۱۱۷"));
    }


    public static int ParseNumeric(string input)
    {
        return int.Parse(string.Concat(input.Select(c =>
            "+-".Contains(c)
                ? c.ToString()
                : char.GetNumericValue(c).ToString())));
    }
}
```

And if you want to support `double`, replace `int` with `double` and add a `.` in the string before `Contains()`.

If you prefer to use `TryParse` instead of a basic `Parse` here you go:

```
public static bool TryParseNumeric(string input, out int numeric)
{
    return int.TryParse(string.Concat(input.Select(c =>
        "+-".Contains(c)
            ? c.ToString()
            : char.GetNumericValue(c).ToString())), out numeric);
}
```