# Error converting string to int

Tags: c#, web-scraping, codepages

I was scraping a page, and I tried to convert some text from page to int,
but I got

> input string was not in correct format
>   text is not in English: "۲۳"

But the page codepage is Utf8

At first I tried, int.parse, Convert.ToInt32. No luck, then

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(eventTime);
var bytDestination = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, bytes);
var resultString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytDestination);
```

no luck,Same error, (i tried other codepages , like "Default" , "ASCII")

I checked with:

```
char.IsDigit(eventTimeHourMinue[0]);
char.IsDigit(eventTimeHourMinue[1]);
```

Noth return true.

How should I Convert this string to int?

Comment: There is no `Convert`/`Parse` method that I know of that will convert textual numbers in one language to integers. Just like there is no built-in method to convert `one` to `1`.

Comment: If you know what digit `۲` is (and what its nine companions are), write a conversion function to convert that set of digits into regular 0-9 digits that `Int32.Parse()` will understand.

Comment: I'm doing it right know, but i don't like it doing it this was, kinda hope to be some "cleaner way"

Comment: @Amirreza Just steal the function maccettura linked to, I do it all the time. If he gets hit by a truck, I'll lose my job. [This looks like the best answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30733198/424129), I think.

Comment: @maccettura THAT SHOULD DO IT, thanx

Comment: I agree with @EdPlunkett about the best answer, although I would make sure you use proper casing since that OP did not

Comment: it worked, let's go give some Like to original poster