# How to have numeric digits in a string to not convert to another language (eg Arabic)

Tags: c#, string.format

I have code thus..

```
string text1 = "more text";
string text2 = string.Format("some text plus {0}", text1);
```

I convert it to Arabic:

```
string text1 = "المزيد من النص";
string text2 = string.Format("بعض النص بالإضافة إلى {0}", text1);
```

So far no problems!

I then switch my computer's language from English to Arabic and look at the code and the numbers have been automatically update to Arabic digits...

```
string text1 = "المزيد من النص";
string text2 = string.Format("{.} بعض النصوص بالإضافة إلى", text1);
```

(I had to fudge this using a period, but the Arabic symbol for 0 looks similar enough for this example).

Trouble is, when the Windows selected language is in Arabic, I am getting a string format exception error because the Format command is not recognising the Arabic symbol for zero.

To be specific, my question is: How do you ensure that the zero entered remains as a Latin digit, even when in a non-Latin language? or How can I get this to work without erroring?

EDIT:

Cut and paste straight from the IDE : first one Windows set to English, second picture, same code, Arabic...

[image: English]

[image: Arabic]

Comment: What if you try with `String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "...", ...)`?

Comment: As I understand it, that would affect the whole string. I only want to maintain the integrity of the tag. There are times when I have other numbers in the string.

Comment: *"the numbers have been automatically update to Arabic digits"* - there is no automatic updates of strings. Or numbers in strings. From where this string with `{.}` comes? I'd expect you have localized strings and arabic strings are loaded when you switch the language. So someone simply did a mistake while localizing `{0}` sequences in text in arabic localization.

Comment: @Sinatr Apparently not so. In english the string is "بعض النص بالإضافة إلى {0}", but when viewed when windows is set to Arabic, the zero gets updated to the Arabic symbol (which looks like a dot). When back to Windows-English, it looks like a normal zero again and the statements run without issue.

Comment: How exactly do you look at string? *"the zero gets updated"* - this is what I don't understand. The string is combination of bytes, the bytes will not change by switching language. I am trying to understand at which step this change occurs.

Comment: Me too. I have updated the question with screen shots. I would have thought that no matter what the symbol for zero looked like, that the underlying '\u0030' would be the same. Best I can tell, it is, but it just will not work in Arabic.

Comment: Do you restart visual studio and it's the same cs-file where `{0}` become `{.}`? I guess it has something to do with cs-file encoding. Visual Studio doesn't load it correctly.

Comment: Do you have all numbers changed to arabic? Like variable names are also have this issue: `var test0` -> `var test.`? What about contstants? Does `000` become `...`? Or the change only happens in strings? Does change occurs to numbers without `{}` too?

Comment: It is just the numbers in the string. Mostly the numbers are already converted (as per Google translate), but the tags are left as is.  But as you can see from the screen captures, the tags needed for string.Format change all by themselves. Changing language by installing language pack then selecting language, signing out and signing back in to effect the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution, with thanks to all who put in comments.

I swapped out all tags `{0}` and replaced with `string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "{0}")`

so now my given example from above looks like...

```
string text1 = "المزيد من النص";
string text2 = string.Format(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "{0}")  + " بعض النصوص بالإضافة إلى", text1);
```

Screen shot for actual code whilst Windows has its language set to Arabic:

[image]

It appears that by using the string.Format in this fashion, that the tags do not revert to Arabic symbols and when each property is put into its own string.Format, it runs without creating an error.

I still do not know why I had to go to all this trouble, like comments above, it should have worked regardless. This to me is a big time hack if ever I saw one!

I did make an initial mistake with secondry tags. I swapped out {1} and replaced with `string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{1}", "{1}")`. Of course this is a sub string.Format command where it still only has one tag.. Dumb error corrected by doing the following...

`string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "{1}")`

Answer (score 0):

`String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"",)`
Should be the way to go, but you need to have the string split into 2 parts :
The First Part contains the Arabic text or the English text.
The second part should contain the Numeric part, and that is the one you should be formatting.

Here is the documentation from Microsoft for you to look at and determine the specific culture that you want to use.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0#System_String_Format_System_IFormatProvider_System_String_System_Object_

Comment: If I could just break up the sections, then I would not need to use the tags in the first place.

Comment: What I mean is that you break the string into two parts, and then add them in one string again 
`string ax = string a + string x`

Comment: I didn't get it why would one need to split string at all? Sure, you found a workaround, but why did the constant string changed?

Comment: @Sinatr I thought about this workaround to make a static part which is the numeric part, and another part that is dynamic which is the text part.

Comment: @Sinatr The numeric part needs to be fixed with a certain format, and the text part is dynamic and changes from one language to another one,

Comment: Why numeric part needs to be fixed? I expect unicode string containing characters from multiple languages (english + arabic) to stay as it is. I can suggest my own workaround - extract arabic text into resource dll, while keeping sources in english. But why this *morphing* of `0` occurs in the first place? It shouldn't

Comment: from what I understood from the question is that he needs the "0" to stay as is in any language, so I thought of this workaround so he can control this specific character with an if statement for example.

Comment: Another workaround idea is [convert arabic digits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5879437/1997232) into english number just before calling `string.Format`.

Comment: Sorry to dip out on the conversation, just had a power cut... I think I have a solution now. I do need the tag to be zero in any language, mostly it is, just having problems with Arabic and probably Bengali. Initial solution, I am swapping out each {0} and replacing with  String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "{0}")  and putting inline.

Comment: @damichab I think that will be a great point, but it will also act as two strings, right?

Comment: @MostafaTarekYassien Will still be a single string, just the tag will be a bit more complicated. I am recreating my 'Arabic' file. I'll write up an explaination/answer in the morning after some testing. Thanking everyone for their help - much appreciated.