# Hijri, Gregorian date and time with arabic Numerals

Tags: date, time, arabic, hijri

I am working on to display the date in Arabic.
That includes Hijri(Islamic) Date, Gregorian Date and time.
The issue is, i want the numerals to be display the arabic numerals not the english ones.
Remember, i can't change the whole page numerals into arabic numerals. Just the script numerals to be converted.
and here is the code:

```
<div align="center">
  <table border="0" width="39%" dir="rtl">
    <tr>
      <td>
<script language="JavaScript">

var fixd;

function isGregLeapYear(year)
{
return year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0 || year%400 == 0;
}


function gregToFixed(year, month, day)
{
var a = Math.floor((year - 1) / 4);
var b = Math.floor((year - 1) / 100);
var c = Math.floor((year - 1) / 400);
var d = Math.floor((367 * month - 362) / 12);

if (month <= 2)
e = 0;
else if (month > 2 && isGregLeapYear(year))
e = -1;
else
e = -2;

return 1 - 1 + 365 * (year - 1) + a - b + c + d + e + day;
}

function Hijri(year, month, day)
{
this.year = year;
this.month = month;
this.day = day;
this.toFixed = hijriToFixed;
this.toString = hijriToString;
}

function hijriToFixed()
{
return this.day + Math.ceil(29.5 * (this.month - 1)) + (this.year - 1) * 354 +
Math.floor((3 + 11 * this.year) / 30) + 227015 - 1;
}

function hijriToString()
{
var months = new Array("محرم","صفر","ربيع أول","ربيع ثانى","جمادى أول","جمادى ثانى","رجب","شعبان","رمضان","شوال","ذو القعدة","ذو الحجة");
return this.day + " " + months[this.month - 1]+ " " + this.year;
}

function fixedToHijri(f)
{
var i=new Hijri(1100, 1, 1);
i.year = Math.floor((30 * (f - 227015) + 10646) / 10631);
var i2=new Hijri(i.year, 1, 1);
var m = Math.ceil((f - 29 - i2.toFixed()) / 29.5) + 1;
i.month = Math.min(m, 12);
i2.year = i.year;
i2.month = i.month;
i2.day = 1;
i.day = f - i2.toFixed() + 1;
return i;
}

var tod=new Date();
var weekday=new Array("الأحد","الإثنين","الثلاثاء","الأربعاء","الخميس","الجمعة","السبت");
var monthname=new Array("يناير","فبراير","مارس","إبريل","مايو","يونيو","يوليو","أغسطس","سبتمبر","أكتوبر","نوفمبر","ديسمبر");

var y = tod.getFullYear();
var m = tod.getMonth();
var d = tod.getDate();
var dow = tod.getDay();
document.write(weekday[dow] + " " + d + " " + monthname[m] + " " + y);
m++;
fixd=gregToFixed(y, m, d);
var h=new Hijri(1421, 11, 28);
h = fixedToHijri(fixd);
document.write(" م | " + h.toString() + "هـ");

</script> 
        | 
<script>
<!-- Clock Code -->
var dayarray=new Array("","","","","","","")
var montharray=new Array("","","","","","","","","","","","")
function getthedate(){
var mydate=new Date()
var year=mydate.getYear()
if (year < 1000)
year+=1900
var day=mydate.getDay()
var month=mydate.getMonth()
var daym=mydate.getDate()
if (daym<10)
daym="0"+daym
var hours=mydate.getHours()
var minutes=mydate.getMinutes()
var seconds=mydate.getSeconds()
var dn="H:i"
if (hours>=12)
dn="مساءً"
else
dn="صباحاً"
if (hours>12){
hours=hours-12
}
if (hours==0)
hours=12
if (minutes<=9)
minutes="0"+minutes
if (seconds<=9)
seconds="0"+seconds
var cdate="<small><font color='000000' face='Times New Roman'>"+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+" "+dn+"</font></small>"
if (document.all)
document.all.clock.innerHTML=cdate
else if (document.getElementById)
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML=cdate
else
document.write(cdate)
}
if (!document.all&&!document.getElementById)
getthedate()
function goforit(){
if (document.all||document.getElementById)
setInterval("getthedate()",1000)
}
         </script> 
        <span id="clock">
        <body onLoad="goforit()">
        </span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, actually those are [Arabic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals), and you are looking for Arabic-Indic Numbers. See this, it may answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675786/convert-from-english-digits-to-arabic-ones-in-html-page/1675970#1675970

Comment: Thnx for the reply @Sneetsher.

I'm not good in javascript. So i don't know how to do that.
Can you help in it Plz?

Comment: You have arrays for the month names and for the day names. You could do exactly the same thing for the numbers. Make an array with the Arabic-script numerals. (Remember to start with zero.) Then, when you want to display a number, just use the numeral from the array, the same way as you use the month names and day names from the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertDigitIn(enDigit){ // PERSIAN, ARABIC, URDO
    var newValue="";
    for (var i=0;i<enDigit.length;i++)
    {
        var ch=enDigit.charCodeAt(i);
        if (ch>=48 && ch<=57)
        {
            // european digit range
            var newChar=ch+1584;
            newValue=newValue+String.fromCharCode(newChar);
        }
        else
            newValue=newValue+String.fromCharCode(ch);
    }
    return newValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest for you to use HIJRI date script from [AR-PHP](http://www.ar-php.org/ar-example-Date-php-arabic.html) , it's useful and very easy to edit.

to change numbers to arabic Numerals you need to change numbers [font-face](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp) in css