# Converting strings to ints when the input is not sequential

Tags: javascript, regex, string, int, special-characters

I have a function in which I'm converting an input string (arabic numeral) into an int value. I do this with the following function.

```
function convertToEnglishDigit(input) {
    var numberMap = {
        '۰': '0',
        '۱': '1',
        '۲': '2',
        '۳': '3',
        '۴': '4',
        '۵': '5',
        '۶': '6',
        '۷': '7',
        '۸': '8',
        '۹': '9',        
    };
    var result = parseInt(input.replace(/[۰-۹]/g, function(i) {
       return numberMap[i];
    }));

    return result;
}
```

It works if the input is either a single character, such as `'۲'` or if the string of characters are sequential such as `'۱۲۳۴۵'`. If the input is a string of characters which are out of order such as `"٢١٠"` the returned value of the `replace()` is `NaN`, why is this and how can I account for the situation in which they are out of order, which in my use case, will be almost always.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675786/convert-from-english-digits-to-arabic-ones-in-html-page this should help you

Comment: Those characters are really confusing for Firebug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, the regex is very confused by those literal characters. You can make it work by using the hex codes for those digits:

```
function convertToEnglishDigit(input) {
    var numberMap = {
      '\u0660': '0',
      '\u0661': '1',
      '\u0662': '2',
      '\u0663': '3',
      '\u0664': '4',
      '\u0665': '5',
      '\u0666': '6',
      '\u0667': '7',
      '\u0668': '8',
      '\u0669': '9'        
    };
    var result = parseInt(input.replace(/[\u0660-\u0669]/g, function(i) {
       return numberMap[i];
    }));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Good Find! I wonder if I even need to map the values in the object. Seems just using the number strings and the hex codes in the replace would be enough.

Comment: any idea how I could handle floating point numbers with this method?

Comment: @Stavros_S well it depends on the notation. If it's similar to Western notation except with different characters for decimal point etc, then the process would be almost identical.

Comment: I tried adding `'\u066B': '.'` to the number map, and changed the `parseInt()` to a `parseFloat()` but I'm getting an error stating 'input.replace is not a function'

Comment: @Stavros_S that means that you're not passing a string to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one , as i am not familiar with this alphabets but it seems to giving the right output . You can modify the code for more efficiency .

```
function convertToEnglishDigit(input){
 var digit =  ['۰','۱','۲','۳','۴','۵','۶','۷','۸','۹'];
 var store = '';
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      if(input[i] === digit[j]) store +=j;
}
}
return parseInt(store);
}
```

**output :**

```
convertToEnglishDigit('۰۱۲۹')
129
convertToEnglishDigit('۰۸۹۲۳۴')
89234
convertToEnglishDigit('۶۱۹۰')
6190
convertToEnglishDigit('۲۱۰')
210
```